# Can you use DataTable.Contains(object key) if your datatable's primary key is two columns?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ado.net, datatable, datarow

if so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select by a primary key you should use one of:

- `DataTable.Rows.Find(Object)` in case your PK is one column
- `DataTable.Rows.Find(Object[])` in case you have more then 1 column as a primary key

In case of a typed DataSet, the method `MyDataTable.Rows.Find(...)` will be generated for you with the proper signature. Basically it is a method on DataRowCollection class

Answer (score 0):

'Contains' does not seem to be a member of the DataRow class (maybe this is a typed data set?)

In any case, you can always use (DataTable.Select(....).Length > 0) as a substitute

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to the DataRowCollection.Contains method ? There is an overload that takes an array of objects, you should use this one

Comment: I tried that, but it tells me "Expecting 2 value(s) for the key being indexed, but received 1 value(s)."

Comment: Did you try that ? table.Contains(new object[] { valueOfFirstKey, valueOfSecondKey })